# Java specific character counter

Tags: java

So I am trying to prompt the user to enter any words into a string. Then I want to prompt them to count the number of occurrences for whatever letter they want to count. So if they enter words in a string like "this is a test" and they search "t" for example, the return would be 3 t's in the string "this is a test". I am a little confused as to where to go from here...

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String inputValue;
String s = "";

System.out.print("Enter a string of words or type done to exit: ");
inputValue = input.readLine();

System.out.print("Which letter would you like to count: ");
s = input.readLine();

int counter = 0;
```

I am thinking about maybe doing a for loop and do something like `counter++`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Apache [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) you could simply do

```
int counter = StringUtils.countMatches(s, intputValue);
```

But if you really want to code it, then you could use

```
public int count(String fullString, char valueToCount)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < fullString.length(); i++)
    {
        if (fullString.charAt(i) == valueToCount)
             count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Another solution would consist of replacing everything in your string except the input char and return the length of the trimmed string.

```
return s.replaceAll("[^" + inputValue + "]", "").length();
```

Comment: I like the quick and easy use of s.replaceAll and search for the specific letter. Instead of having a loop, with several lines of code, one single line is much easier to read.

Comment: @HelloWorld I agree, but the one from `Apache` is also one line and contains a lot of useful functions for working with string, you might want to check the link I put in my answer :). Anyway, glad I helped.

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided by Jean above is correct but I would like use a different method to calculate number of occurrence of a character in a String.

```
String string = "this is a testing string";
int count = string.length() - string.replaceAll("t", "").length();
```

Or

```
int counter = string.split("t").length - 1;
```

You would need to escape meta characters if you are to check character like `$`.

Comment: I would suggest the split method but @Wilts C did it first. :) About the quotation, I think it is important and this would help:
    int counter = string.split(Pattern.quote(string)).length - 1;